# Spring Batch - Parallel Processing - Flow config

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I wonder is this possible to create a flow like this?

STEP1_> (FLOW_1 | split | FLOW_2) _> STEP_2 _> (FLOW_3 | split | FLOW_4) _> STEP_3 ...
...
Each flow has same identical steps that work with a different data source.

Please kindly advise if this kind of job configuration can be achieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate `FLOW_1 | split | FLOW_2` in a flow (named `parallel_flow` for example) and create a sequential flow like step1 -> parallel_flow -> step2 -> parallel_flow ... Encapsulation FTW!